# fprintf not writing to file

Tags: c, file-io

For some reason, my fprintf statement does nothing. I put printf statements around it to see if it even gets to it (which it does), but I still can't figure out why nothing happens. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char c[8];
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *fp2;
  int i=0;
  int count,j,temp=0;

  fp = fopen(argv[0],"r");
  fp2 = fopen(argv[1], "w");

  for(i=0; i<50;i++)
    {
        count = fread(c,1,8,fp);
        if(((4<i)&&(i<10))||((14<i)&&(i<20))||((24<i)&&(i<30))||((34<i)&&(i<40))||(44<i)){
        continue;
    }
    else{
        for(j = 0; j<count; j++){
            c[j]=c[j]-'0';
            c[j]=c[j] << (count - (j+1));
            temp = temp | c[j];
      }
        fprintf(fp2, "%d\n", temp);
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp2);
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried multiple things but can't figure it out!

Thanks!.

Comment: if you want `fopen(argv[0],"r");`, change file mode `"r"` to `"rb"`.

Comment: Check the return values from `fopen`.

Comment: Perhaps stepping through with a debugger might help, too.

Comment: Not necessarily the problem, but the indentation is screwed up and it makes the code hard to follow.  Could you please fix that?

Comment: @MichaelBurr yup, down and close voting for gross debug fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of `argv`. If you want to pass two arguments, as in

```
./myprog infile outfile
```

the name `infile` will be in `argv[1]`, not in `argv[0]`. Same goes for `outfile`, it will be in `argv[2]`:

```
fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
```

For completeness, the standard specifies the content of `argv[0]` as follows:

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment.

Answer (score 0):

You're grabbing the wrong arguments.

`argv[0]` is always the name of the program being run.  Command line options passed the the program start with `argv[1]`.

What actually you're doing is reading the executable file and writing to your input file.

So instead of this:

```
fp = fopen(argv[0],"r");
fp2 = fopen(argv[1], "w");
```

You want this:

```
// check for the proper number of arguments first
if (argc < 3) {
    printf("usage: program file1 file2\n");
    exit(1);
}
fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
```